# Unable to Start User Profile Synchronization Service in Share Point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I try to create User Profile Site in SharePoint 2013 SP1 with is install on Windows server 2012 R2.and Sharepoint Database on MSSQL Server 2014 with on another VM Machine.and also my farm user is already added into server local Administrator Group.

So any one has solutions about this issue please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: check the event log and ULS for more clue and share the error

Answer (score 3):

Spence Harbar has [put-up a detailed documentation on possible problems](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/10/30/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-service-stuck-on-starting/) and resolutions. You should look into specifics and isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UPS bible written by Spence Harbar (for sharepoint 2010, but everything is the same in 2013):
http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

In short:

Before starting:
Grant „Allow logon Locally“ to domain\spFarm account and add domain\spFarm to local admins on application Server.

Create new Web Application and site collection for mysites host: for example http://mysites using Content app pool running account domain\spContent

Create new User Profile Service Application
Service app pool is „Sharepoint Web Services Default“ running by domain\spService

Log on with domain\spFarm, then log of, then log on again (for user policies be applied correctly)

and start:

User Profile Service, then started:

User Profile Synchronization Service (wait about 2 min while starting),

then started:

IISRESET

Log off

Log on domain\spadmin 
Remove domain\spFarm from local admins

Add domain\spFarm to „Allow log on locally“

Add domain\spFarm  to „Log on as service“

Check the permissions on 
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FIMSynchronizationService\Parameters and see if your Farm Account is present. If not – add spfarm account with read permissions.

In windows services find Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service and set the startup type to Automatic (Delayed Start). Then grant the Network Service account basic "Read & Execute/List folder contents/Read" permissions to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0 directory.

After starting services Configure Profile Synchronization connection using domain\spProfileSync

If stuck on starting:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Synchronization Service"} 


Stop-SPServiceInstance ups-service-guid-blablablabla
```